Why does Victor Timely say "pumpkins" in this scene?
Loki Season 2, episode 6, the finale.
When Victor Timely has just completed the momentous task of "fixing" the Temporal Loom, he returns along the bridge/promontory to the TVA in triumph (13 minutes, 35 seconds into the episode in the Disney version).
His first word after the initial success is "pumpkins".
It could simply be a quirk of the character that his first thought goes to that form of food, or perhaps the writers were paying a tribute to National Pumpkin Day (US: October 26th). The episode itself was releases on November 9th in the US, so close enough perhaps.
Is there any specific known reason that pumpkins are introduced at this point, be it in-canon or a statement by the producers/writers giving us the reason?

https://contingentmagazine.org/2023/02/26/aint-i-some-pumpkins/
